# Webpack 3 Error after using the same name for file and class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I noticed this error after renaming my files to use the same name as the class name.

e.g

```
class School {}
```

file name: `School.jsx` and the file was imported using:

```
import  School from ./School
```

Below is the error I am getting from Webpack.

```
WARNING in ./client/components/admin/includes/HeaderSideBar.jsx
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /Users/developer/Desktop/Books/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/developer/Desktop/Books/client/components/admin/includes/HeaderSideBar.jsx
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/developer/Desktop/Books/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/developer/Desktop/Books/client/components/admin/pages/AddANewBook.jsx
* /Users/developer/Desktop/Books/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/developer/Desktop/Books/client/components/admin/includes/HeaderSidebar.jsx
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/developer/Desktop/Books/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/developer/Desktop/Books/client/components/admin/index.jsx
webpack: Compiled with warnings.
```

Have you ever come across this type of problem and how did you tackle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is not related to using the same name for the class and the file, and neither is it related to the `School` name/file. The warning tells you that you have two files that have the same name, except for the case of at least on character (instead of a lowercase you have an uppercase or vice versa).

```
components/admin/includes/HeaderSideBar.jsx
components/admin/includes/HeaderSidebar.jsx
```

`HeaderSideBar.jsx` and `HeaderSidebar.jsx` are two different files (the `B` is capitalised in one of them). This can be a problem because some file systems are case-*in*sensitive, which means when you ask for a file that doesn't exist, let's say `file.js`, it will gladly give you `FILE.js` if that one exists. Whereas a case-sensitive file system would just tell you that `file.js` doesn't exist and result in an error. In that case you would have a working application on one file system and a broken one on the other. Similarly if both files are used it might be possible that both uses will resolve to the same file, even though you expected something else.

To avoid this potential problem, you should not have two files with the same name. The file system differences aside, it's not a good idea to use the same name with different casing, because it makes it harder to distinguish which file you need to edit.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.